# Display related problems during Debian installation

Tags: system-installation, debian-installer

I am building a new PC, and I can’t install Debian. When I start my USB boot drive, I see the booting menu as below.

[image]

Then when I select "Graphical install" and I get the following problem:

[image]

When I tried to select simple “Install", I got the same result:

[image]

My CPU is Ryzen 2200G with Vega GPU.

Comment: A related question (I don't use Debian so I can't tell whether this is a true duplicate): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291498/screen-corrupted-after-booting-debian-8-5-installer

Comment: This looks like either a driver screwup or a graphics mode that the monitor can't handle. It's been ages since I installed Debian, but the first thing I'd try is to press Ctrl-Alt-F1 to see if text consoles are enabled, both from the initial menu and from the screwed-up screen. If you can get to a text console from the screwed up screen, next step is to check `dmesg` and/or `Xorg.log` for what drivers it loaded, and what it thinks it did when it switched modes.

Comment: Console are broken too. It looks like problem @Kusalananda said. I think it happens becouse Debian 9 use 4.9 kernal as defoult. But Ryzen 3 2200g is new processor and kernal support since 4.17 version. =(

Comment: I had a old Debian 9 on my HDD. and now I run it. But I got a lot another problems - gruphic is terrible and my eyes are very tired. I think I'll stop at the ubuntu until it turns out Debian 10

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this exact same issue. I managed to get it going by disabling CSM (Compatibility Support Mode) in the BIOS. This forces the installer into full UEFI mode and it is happy after that.

Answer (score 2):

I would try with the second option `Install` as sometimes the graphical installation would have problems with driver. I had similar issues with one of my old PCs.

Comment: I tryed. Last photo it is. =)

Comment: ok. I am sorry, I didn't read between pictures.

Comment: Similar issue that is left unanswered for more than a year.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371006/glitchy-debian-install-screen-both-standard-and-graphical

Comment: Please share your solution if you have worked around.

Answer (score 2):

I have same behaviour of my Vega FE. 
And it is a simple way to resolve it.
Boot uder UEFI mode and install in simple mode (not Graphics) second position in menu.

And install ask force or not UEFI mode? i use not.
And got normal legacy/console version.

Answer (score 2):

help--> boot:
install vga=normal fb=off

or

help--> boot:
expert vga=normal fb=off

Answer (score 0):

Choose the help menu option and then select the option asking about the display.

"old laptops use VGA=...."

Then I was prompted with about 2 dozen display options. Choose a mode by entering the single alphanumeric option corresponding to your setup.

No mouse support, but I can see now.

Comment: Thanks Ian, with that fixed, just have to fix wifi firmware (nonfree) and it will be on rails!